# Comparar Listas independente do índice Python

Tags: python, array, python-3.x

Boa tarde,

Necessito comparar 2 listas e quando um determinado valor no campo 'name' da lista 1 não existir no campo 'name' da lista 2 executar alguma função.

Do modo que fiz está comparando índice por índice e executando o if toda vez que os campos são diferentes, mas no caso quero executar somente quando não existir o valor em nenhum indice da lista 2

```
dados1 = [{'name': 'Polo Pedreira', 'id': '02'},
            {'name': 'Polo Itu', 'id': '01'}]

dados2 = [{'name': 'Polo Jaguariuna', 'id': '03'},
           {'name': 'Polo Itu', 'id': '04'}]

for dadost1 in dados1:
    for dadost2 in dados2:
        if dadost1['name'] != dadost2['name']:
            print(dadost2)
```

Ele está me retornando isso:

> {'name': 'Polo Jaguariuna', 'id': '03'}
>   {'name': 'Polo Itu', 'id': '04'}
>   {'name': 'Polo Jaguariuna', 'id': '03'}

Obrigado desde já

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Levando como base o pensamento do [Alex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/120724/alexciuffa), refiz meu código:

```
listaNomes=[]
for nome in dados2:
    listaNomes.append(nome['name'])

for dadost1 in dados1:
    if dadost1['name'] not in listaNomes:
        print(dadost1)
```

Me retornou o único dado na primeira lista inexistente na segunda lista:

> {'name': 'Polo Pedreira', 'id': '02'}

Comment: Que bom que meu codigo ajudou, mas o seu está muuuito melhor hahaha

Comment: marque o seu como resposta certa então

Comment: Pensei que não poderia fazer isso, obrigado por avisar hahaha. Obs: tentei aqui mas ele só me deixa fazer isso amanhã.

Answer (score 3):

Pensei na seguinte solução:

1) Pegar os nomes como uma lista de nomes

```
def pega_nomes_de_dicionario(lista):
    lista_nomes=[]
    for dic in lista:
        lista_nomes.append(dic['name'])
    return lista_nomes

>>> nomes_dados1 = pega_nomes_de_dicionario(dados1)
>>> nomes_dados2 = pega_nomes_de_dicionario(dados2)
>>> print nomes_dados1
['Polo Pedreira', 'Polo Itu']
```

2) verificar quais nomes só tem em uma lista e não na outra

```
def pega_nomes_fatantes(nomes_dados1, nomes_dados2):
    nomes_faltantes = []

    for nome in nomes_dados1:
        if nome not in nomes_dados2:
            nomes_faltantes.append(nome)

    return nomes_faltantes

>>>> nomes_faltantes = pega_nomes_fatantes(nomes_dados1, nomes_dados2)
>>>> print nomes_faltantes
['Polo Pedreira']
```

3) Pegar o dado completo dos nomes faltantes

```
def pega_dado_completo(nomes_faltantes, dados1, dados2):
    for dado in dados1:
        if dado['name'] in nomes_faltantes:
            print(dado)

>>> pega_dado_completo(nomes_faltantes, dados1, dados2)
{'name': 'Polo Pedreira', 'id': '02'}
```

Comment: Boa noite Alex, levei seu pensamento como base e escrevi novamente o meu código, refazendo-o mais objetivo possível.